# PIVOT/UNPIVOT Table

Tags: sql, pivot, unpivot

I have a table like this:

```
Source Participation Improvement ReportType
    A           1           2        Grantee
    B           3           4        National
```

And I want to Pivot it into:

```
Source   Category      Grantee National
  A     Participation     1       3
  B     Improvement       2       4
```

Heres what I have so far, but I dont even know if its possible. Should I be using a pivot and unpivot? Or just a pivot?

```
    select Source, [National]
    from
   (
        MyTable
   ) d
  UNPIVOT
  (
    [National] FOR Source
    in (Participation,Improvement)
  ) piv
```

Comment: I think there is a problem: Your Source "B", ReportType "National" = 3 Participatoin is displayed in your result in Source A. I would go for a case when + sum + union scenario in this case. You would receive 4 rows - or am I missing something? :-)